# Why is new Date() returning the wrong timezone in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, date

```
userAgent：`Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/68.0.3440.7 Safari/537.36`
```

In Chrome Devtools, running `new Date(1899, 1, 10)` will yield the string:

```
Fri Feb 10 1899 00:00:00 GMT+0805 (中国标准时间)
```

But in other browsers it returns:

```
Fri Feb 10 1899 00:00:00 GMT+0800 (中国标准时间)
```

`0800` is correct. Why does 0805 appear?

Comment: `GMT+0805` ... wow! there's some weird stuff going on at chrome headquarters ... have you tried the current chrome? 67? 68 seems to be a beta release so may have bugs ... like non-existent timezones

Comment: Guess what I got? `Fri Feb 10 1899 00:00:00 GMT+0646 (Malaysia Time)`. Running on version 67

Comment: I correctly received `Fri Feb 10 1899 00:00:00 GMT+0530 (IST)` on `Version 66.0.3359.181 (Official Build) (64-bit)`

Comment: maybe back in 1899, there were no timezones like we have today, and Chrome guesses the zone from the geographic longitude of the current location

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looking at [this website](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zone/china/shanghai), for Shanghai, they had a `GMT+0805` from < 1800 up to 1900.

[image]

This changed in 1901 when they removed the extra 5 minutes, becoming `GMT+0800`.

[image]

Same reason why user [Thum Choon Tat](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6624509/thum-choon-tat) gets [`GMT+0646`.](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/zone/malaysia/kuala-lumpur?year=1899) in the comments.

This said, it looks like Chrome goes a little further than other browsers in determining the timezone.

Comment: What chrome is doing is to have a correct representation of the time back then. Assume that you want to have a time difference between a moment in that period and, let's say the start of WWII, then it should return with the right amounts of milliseconds.The java 8 time API has such exceptions too. Shanghai is not alone with that.

Comment: @KarelG Yes you are correct. Note I'm merely using Shanghai here as one example but there are, of course, many.

Comment: Not a lot people is aware of that. I discovered it (with other exceptions) when troubleshooting a bug issue in an old module which was caused by - what a coincidence - Shanghai's time representation before 1901.

Comment: @GavinYang I don't know how this is implemented in Chrome. Could be that there are differences in the Windows and Mac builds. Or perhaps the underlying OS makes the difference.On my Mac, for Belgium where I live, I indeed also only get the 'modern' timezones if you can call it so.